# What interacts with the DotNetNuke UserLogin function found in the AspNetMembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dotnetnuke, bll

I'm trying to figure out where the login functionality is that interacts with the UserLogin function of the AspNetMembershipProvider section, there's no references to where the login functionality exists. I know this is the function to intact with the data, I just need to find where in the source code the login is so I can customize the login (eg. redirect on login based on user roles, personalized message, etc)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found it, just a bit blind. Login.aspx.cs had it, it was just in the private members section and I was looking in the event handlers section.